# How to perform Permutation Feature importance?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-mining, predictive-modeling, feature-selection

I am trying to perform feature selection. Currently with Tree based classifiers, even randomly generated column is ranking above some of my real columns. So I was reading about `PFI`. Can someone help me understand the steps to be followed?

1) Have my data in csv file

2) Fill in missing values/clean/prepare data

3) Split the data into train and test

4) Standardize train and test data

5) Select a model (let's say logistic regression)

6) Fit train data to logreg model

7) Predict using input test data

I have given the code below for my model

```
logreg=LogisticRegression() # step 5
logreg_cv.fit(X_train_std,y_train) # step 6
y_pred = logreg_cv.predict(X_test_std) # step 7
```

Would really be helpful if you could kind of explain in a way a noob can understand. I am new to ML, so it would really be helpful

Where does `PFI` fit in here? I see that we have `eli5` package but couldn't find an example yet.

**update - my code after suggested solution**

```
logreg=LogisticRegression()
pi=PermutationImportance(logreg, cv=2).fit(X_train_std,y_train) # error is in this line. 
rfe=RFECV(pi, step=1, n_jobs=-1, cv=5, scoring="auc").fit(X_train_std,y)
y_pred = rfe.predict(X_test_std)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok lets answer this with some basic steps:

Yo have done what you said **until 5-th step** after that you **could** do:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from eli5.sklearn import PermutationImportance
pi=PermutationImportance(logreg, cv=2).fit(X_train,y)
selector=RFECV(pi, step=10, n_jobs=-1, cv=2, scoring="f1_macro").fit(X_train,y)
```

now make predictions

`selector.predict(X_test)`

or plot the most important features

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(selector.grid_scores_)`

Comment: this method can be used with any model. right? i mean instead of logreg, i can also use `xgboost`.

Comment: Thats right, any object that is compactible with "estimator" in docs : https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodocs/sklearn.html#eli5.sklearn.permutation_importance.PermutationImportance

Comment: Hi, I keep encountering issue in the line `i=PermutationImportance(logreg, cv=2).fit(X_train,y)`. that `alueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
`

Comment: Please find my code incorporating your suggestion above in the post. Please note that `X_train_std` is the standardized input data whereas `y_train` is the binary label column with `1s and 0s`

Comment: But `X_train_std` has no `NA` or `inf`. Not sure why it causes this error